# Striped pattern for a custom shape in swift UI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, cs193p

I am learning Swift with the cs193p online class https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/.

One of the assignment entails creating a custom shape (like a diamond) and then applying a striped pattern to its background (with different colors).

I was wondering whats a good way to approach this (without using images if possible). Looked around quite a bit but don't even know where to start. In general, is there any way

Googled around a bit but couldn't find any good solutions.

Comment: UIBezierPath to draw custom shapes. Stripped pattern with different colors can be a "Gradient", or a small image (could be created) that is used as a pattern

Comment: Look at the Apple SwiftUI tutorials there is a whole section for shapes and one is a rounded diamond

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.  Create a `Shape` called `Stripes`:

```
struct Stripes: Shape {
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        let width = rect.size.width
        let height = rect.size.height
        
        for x in stride(from: 0, through: width, by: width / 9) {
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: height))
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

Then when you are drawing a striped shape:

```
ZStack {
    // Draw the stripes clipped to the shape
    Stripes()
        .stroke(lineWidth: 2 * scale)
        .clipShape(shape)

    // Draw the shape outline
    shape.stroke(lineWidth: 4 * scale)
}
.frame(width: 150, height: 100)
```

where `scale` is a `CGFloat` that you'll want to vary depending on the size of the shape that you are drawing.  Start with a value of `1.0` and make it larger to get the right look.  `shape` is one of `Rectangle()`, `Capsule()`, or `Diamond()`.